# MMVM Light Using WCF Asynchronously

Tags: wcf, mvvm

What is a good practice to implement MMVM with WCF Services? The View model will be communicating with the service. So lets say in a view I have 3-4 data display modules. All this information for the modules is coming from different WCF Service calls. 
If I do this synchronously, I have a feeling that the data in the view model will take time to load.

I want to do the calls for all these service methods asynchronously with out waiting for the first call to come back. What is good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to call the Service Asynchronously and then assign value on Complete method, like:

```
 class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> data;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            if (value == data) return;
            data = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        GetDataClient proxy = new GetDataClient();

        System.EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs> Client_GetDataCompleted = null;
        Client_GetDataCompleted = (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
            {
                Data = new ObservableCollection<SelectionItem<string>>(e.Result));                    
            }

            proxy.GetDataCompleted -= Client_GetDataCompleted;
        };

        proxy.GetDataCompleted += Client_GetDataCompleted;            
        proxy.GetDataAsync();            
    }
}
```